# Deploy multiple releases on cloud foundry infrastructure

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am trying to deploy multiple releases (e.g. cassandra cf-release, mysql cf-release, elasticsearch cf-release)  on a BOSH based CF instance .  For every individual release listed above,  I have a deployment manifest file which lists components to  deploy  cloud foundry  and service associated to the release.  Since the infrastructure related to CF is already deployed and running, I wanted to know if there is a way in deployment manifest to point to currently running CF. Currently, I am repeating the deployment information for CF in every single service release and this causes BOSH to deploy CF for every single release.

To summarize, I want to have various 2 types of  deployment  manifests as the  following:

1. CF only release  (infrastructure, networks, jobs and properties only for CF deployment)
2. Service only CF release -  (point to currently running CF + infrastructure, networks, jobs and properties only for service deployment)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your active interest in CloudFoundry. To achieve what you are trying to, you can have one manifest to deploy and then you can add / remove / edit jobs and packages and redeploy and it will only update and deploy the services you have made changes to.
Hope that helps!

Let me know if you have any other queries.

Comment: Hi Hitesh, Thanks for your comments. I am trying to find out if there is a way to split the deployment manifests limited to jobs listed in the manifest. I want to have manifest file which includes jobs and packages only specific to the release. For example,

Comment: Hi Hitesh, 
Thanks for your comments. I am trying to find out if there is a way to split the deployment manifests limited to jobs and packages listed in the manifest. For example, cf-release manifest should list jobs and packages related to cloud foundry release.Then, for services hosted on cloud foundry (e.g. cassandra-release, mysql-release), I want to have jobs and packages related to services excluding cf-release jobs and packages. Since, CF is already deployed and running from cf-release deployment, don't want to repeat the cf-release jobs and packages in  services manifest file.

Comment: Hi, For more options on how to handle this situation, you will get better answers here : https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/bosh-users.

Thanks,
Hitesh